# Can't start mysql and my.cnf is missing

Tags: mysql

For some reason, I can't start MySql.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[sudo] password for abigail: 
Starting MySQL.............................................[FAILED]................................................................................
```

What caused this?

This is what in my /var/lib/mysql

```
$ ll -h /var/lib/mysql
total 1005M
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  16K Mar 28 11:08 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql   52 Mar 28 11:08 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 908M Mar 31 20:10 ibdata1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  48M Mar 31 20:09 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  48M Mar 31 20:10 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    5 Mar 28 11:09 localhost.pid
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    0 Oct 29 23:04 multi-master.info
drwx--x--x. 2 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct 29 23:01 mysql
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql   19 Oct 29 23:01 performance_schema
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  24K Mar 28 11:09 tc.log
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql 4.0K Nov  3 22:10 test
```

I think I might have to reinstall mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`my.cnf` is supposed to be in `/etc/my.cnf`.

Check the start log for the error message, like in `/var/log/mysqld.log`.

Comment: Right. it here! Any idea what's causing the failure?